# Insert status in database

Tags: php, pdo

user_reservation.php

```
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th scope="col">Number of Guest</th>
  <th scope="col">Type of Service</th>
  <th scope="col">Date</th>
  <th scope="col">Time</th>
  <th scope="col">Status</th>
  <th scope="col">Edit</th>

      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php


    include 'include/db_config.php';

    $result = $dbs->prepare("SELECT * FROM service_info WHERE id = :id");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

   ?>
    <tr class="record">
    <td><?php echo $row['no_guest']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type_service']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['datepicker']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['t_time']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $service['status']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="editform.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> edit </a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>

    <b>STATUS</b><br>

    <?php


    include 'include/db_config.php';

    $result = $dbs->prepare("SELECT * FROM service_info WHERE id = :id");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>

  <!--<td><?php //echo $row['datepicker']; ?></td>-->

  <?php
  $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
  $startdate = $row['datepicker'];   
  $offset = strtotime("+2 day");
  $enddate = date($startdate, $offset);    
  $today_date = new DateTime($today);
  $expiry_date = new DateTime($enddate);


   $status = ($expiry_date < $today_date) ? 'Expired' : 'Active' ;
   $result = $dbs->prepare("UPDATE Customers SET status = :status WHERE id =       :id");
   $result->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
   $result->bindParam(':status', $status);
   $result->execute();
  ?>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

This is my whole code on user_reservation. All i wanted on my admin_reservation was to fetch whats inside of my status database . but as you can see i cant still insert the status data in my database

Answer (score 0):

Add a column 'status' in your table 'service_info' using phpMyAdmin for example,
then in your time verification :

```
    include 'include/db_config.php';

 $result = $dbs->prepare("SELECT * FROM service_info WHERE id = :id");
 $result->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['id']);
 $result->execute();
 for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
 ?>

 <?php
 $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
 $startdate = $row['datepicker'];   
 $offset = strtotime("+2 day");
 $enddate = date($startdate, $offset);    
 $today_date = new DateTime($today);
 $expiry_date = new DateTime($enddate);

 $status = ($expiry_date < $today_date) ? 'Expired' : 'Active' ;
 $result = $dbs->prepare("UPDATE Customers SET status = :status WHERE id = :id");
 $result->execute(array(':status'=>$status, ':id'=>$_SESSION['id']));
```

then in your table, just output the status column :

```
<tr class="record">
<td><?php echo $customers[$key]['firstname'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $service['no_guest']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $service['type_service']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $service['datepicker']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $service['t_time']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $service['status']; ?></td>
```

Comment: let me try this sir first .

Comment: I edited some ;), if you get an error, paste it here pls :)

Comment: by the way sir they're in different form.php

Comment: can i edit my post and i guess im gonna try that on the same page